# If DoCmd.SendObject fails?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-office

I am using DoCmd.SendObject to send emails from MS access 2003. It opens the outlook with all relevant fields filled. But the user may not choose to send the email at that time. In that case, a prompt 'Send Action was cancelled' appears. Is there a way to catch this non-sending of email by user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to use Outlook events from Microsoft Access with a class module. You will find details in the [LessThanDot wiki](http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Access_and_Email), under the heading "Example: Use Outlook Events with Access"

Answer (score 1):

You've sent the object to Outlook.

I don't believe there's a way for Outlook to reply to your Access command.

Comment: Unfortunately, this seems to be dead-end then :(

Answer (score 1):

databyss is right when writing there is no way for Outlook to reply to your Access command. Instead of using this loosy "sendObject" command, I'd advise you to create an Outlook instance from your VBA code (after registering the Microsoft Outlook Object Library in tools/references)? You would be then able to manage your emails in a very efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps Tony Toews's [Access EMail FAQ](http://www.granite.ab.ca/Access/email.htm) would be of use to you.